# Separating the number in google sheet as a text format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In the google sheet I want to separate the number only in following text P30709FFE and the result would be generated as a text format

I already separated the number but the result was in a formula mode I want to get the result in plain text mode to put different formula to the above separated number

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244).

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d+")
```